# Adding to Ioc.Default.Configure services from Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am currently moving an `mvvmlight` app to use `Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm` and for the most part, it has been relatively pain free.

I am having an issue though with the addition of services to Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices.

On the platform specfic code, I create a service collection to handle platform specific things (such as Storage, UserSettings etc) like this

```
Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(new ServiceCollection().
           AddSingleton<ISqliteConnectionFactory, SQLConnection>().
           AddSingleton<IFileservice, Storage>().
           AddSingleton<IUserSettings, UserSettings>().BuildServiceProvider());
```

This works fine on both iOS and Android. However, in my `ViewModelLocator` (from the old mvvmlight package), I cannot add anything to the services as the default service collection has already been set up.

Is there a way to add the services in the shared code to the `Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices` once it has been created?

Comment: According to your description, you want to add services in shared code, you can take a look [Configure and resolve services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/ioc#configure-and-resolve-services)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution.

Create the servicecollection on the platform and pass to the App method as an IServiceCollection. This is then passed in the App to the ViewModelLocatior and the services added from there before calling the `BuildServiceProvider` method.